# How to transform url into the correct form in the Yii2 framework

Tags: yii2, yii2-urlmanager

This code `<?php echo Url::to(['/tasks/', 'view' => $task->id]);?>` transforms into the url web/tasks?view=1 what code and where will transform output variants into the web/tasks/view/1?

Comment: With little research you can find this: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing, this should help you understand the principles

Answer (score 0):

**Config File:**

```
'urlManager' => [
        # code...
        'rules' => [
            'tasks/view/<id:\d+>' => 'tasks/view',
         ],
```

**Controller-Action**

```
  public function actionView($id) {
     // $_GET or  \Yii::$app->getRequest()->GET('id')
     $id = ... int id
     # code..
  }
```

**View File:**

```
 <?php echo Url::to(['/tasks/view', 'id' => $task->id]);?>
```